# How to parse tumblr search results page?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, tumblr

There is a Tumblr page with the search results, e.g. https://www.tumblr.com/search/fruit+apple

I need to scrape at least 10 results from it and parse them. How to do that?
It's seems like the Tumblr API doesn't have the appropriate method. And the

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.tumblr.com/search/fruit+apple");
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml); //<--it freezes here
```

method from HtmlAgilityPack doesn't work with this web-address (or I'm doing something wrong).

Is it possible to get the search results? Please help (or say that it's impossible). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to include code showing what you've tried so far and where you're failing.

Comment: @vzwick thanks, done.

Comment: "It freezes here" - is an Exception thrown? If yes, can you add it?

Comment: @vzwick yes, it working for more than a minute then the .NET Fiddle says "Execution time limit was exceeded".

Comment: Also: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged--get-posts-with-tag